# Unable to reference WSDL of WCF web service hosted on AppFabric

Tags: wcf, wsdl, appfabric

I have developed a WCF service and, while in Visual Studio 2010, I can import the WSDL without a problem. After I've deployed it to AppFabric, I get the WSDL, but several schema files referenced internally in the WSDL cannot be found, for some reason. I don't know if it's a configuration issue, or what. The error I get when I try to process the WSDL in Visual Studio 2010 follows below:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://myserver.mydomain.com:9871/app_deploy/MyAppService.svc?wsdl'.
>   The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
>   There was an error downloading 'http://myserver.mydomain.com:9871/app_deploy/MyAppService.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 502: Proxy Error ( The
>   specified network name is no longer available.  ).
>    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://myserver.mydomain.com:9871/app_deploy/MyAppService.svc'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at http://myserver.mydomain.com:9871/app_deploy/MyAppService.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.
>   The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service reference again.

The error is a proxy error because it goes through a proxy, but the error is because the page isn't there. I've tried accessing `http://localhost:9871/app_deploy/MyAppService.svc?xsd=xsd0` at the server, but I get 404.

Why wouldn't these xsd files being found? Is it a deployment issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Man, I finally found the problem [here](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/raimondb/archive/2008/02/14/Unable-to-generate-a-WCF-proxy-using-svcutil-but-retreiving-the-wsdl-works_3F00_.aspx). I needed write permission on C:\Windows\Temp for Application Pool user!